# Sort by distance

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a set of dictionaries in an array. I display this data in a tableview. In the tableview i calculate the distance to each object and display that in the cell.

The data needs to be able to sort based on ascending distance, obviously per userlocation What's the best way to approach this? I thought of picking apart all of the dictionaries and inserting the distance and then letting loose the NSSortDescriptor, problem is, i'm way too lazy for that.

Right now im just looping through all of the data with the indexPath.row and displaying it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can easily sort with a the block based comparator api.

```
NSArray *rawData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:pathDoc];

rawData = [rawData sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) {

    CLLocationDistance dist_a= [[a objectsForKey:@"coordinate"] distanceFromLocation: userPosition];
    CLLocationDistance dist_b= [[b objectsForKey:@"coordinate"] distanceFromLocation: userPosition];
    if ( dist_a < dist_b ) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if ( dist_a > dist_b) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```

You should easy find an implementation for `calculate_distance(user_position, a);` with google.

Comment: I was already calculating the distance with distanceFromLocation: but for one location, i need the latitude and longitude from a dictionary out of the NSArray. I looped this with for() and NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:i], but how i do fit that in with the block based comparator api?

Comment: Some more code here: http://pastebin.com/dndv7dk1 edited a bit to keep it readable.

Comment: Hmm the array NSLog's correctly, and i dont see any anomalities, but when i try to get dict's from the array after running the comparator block, it throws a bad access error. It doesnt get released anywhere yet..

Comment: Sure you are assining rawData to a property. How does it look like?

Comment: Fixed! Thanks vikingosegundo! I pressed upvote 100 times, too bad it only works once.