# Sort array by integers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have an array that named `detailTexts` that having his data from floats:

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:dlog longitude:dlig];
**CLLocationDistance meters = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:location];**
**float detailFloat = meters * 1000;**
if (meters < 10000) {
    NSLog(@"%@", detailText);
    [tableData addObject:name];
    **detailText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", detailFloat];**
    **[detailTexts addObject:detailText];**
}
```

how i can sort the array to get nearly location first? (i know it in mysql: SORT BY ...)

Xcode 4.3 (updated version), Mac OS X Lion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769492/sort-by-distance/7769557#7769557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *sortedArray =
             [detailTexts sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```