# NSMutableArray data sorting by a distance

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Have a problem with my MutableArray. I've the data array in my tableview, and everything is ok, but when the data is sorting by a distance and i'm choosing an item in cell, it shows me incorrect data in new viewcontroller. It shows the data without sorting. It's like a broken link) Hope for your help)

i'm new in obj-c, so i apologise)

here is my code:

```
       list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [list addObject:@{@"name": @"Central office", @"address":@"наб. Обводного канала, д.66А", @"phone":@"+7 (812) 320-56-21 (многоканальный)", @"workTime":@"ПН-ПТ: с 9:30 до 18:30", @"email":@"mail@ibins.ru", @"payment":@"Принимаются к оплате пластиковые карты VISA и MasterCard", @"longitude":@30.336842, @"latitude":@59.913950}];

        [list addObject:@{@"name": @"Second office", @"address":@"ул. Камышовая, д.38", @"phone":@"+7 (812) 992-992-6; +7 (812) 456-26-43", @"workTime":@"Ежедневно: с 9:30 до 20:00", @"email":@"sever@ibins.ru", @"payment":@"Принимаются к оплате пластиковые карты VISA и MasterCard", @"longitude":@30.219863, @"latitude":@60.008805}];

        [list addObject:@{@"name": @"Third office", @"address":@"Street name", @"phone":@"phone number", @"workTime":@"Work time", @"email":@"email address", @"longitude":@30.294254, @"latitude":@60.028728}]; 

    [self constructList];
    [self constructPins];
    }



- (IBAction)switchDisplayType:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.80];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    if ([(UISegmentedControl*)sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 1) {
        map.hidden = YES;
        contentSV.hidden = NO;
    }
    else {
        map.hidden = NO;
        contentSV.hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    static NSString* BridgeAnnotationIdentifier = @"bridgeAnnotationIdentifier";

    MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                           initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:BridgeAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
    customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    customPinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;

    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
   // NSLog(@"%@",rightButton);
    [rightButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(annotationButtonTapped:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    return customPinView;//[kml viewForAnnotation:annotation];
}

- (void)annotationButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    DetailVC *sampleVC = [[DetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sampleVC animated:YES];
    [sampleVC release];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in list) {
        if ([[dict valueForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:selectedAnnTitle]) {
            [sampleVC updateViewWithDict:dict];
        }
    }
}



- (void)constructPins {
    for (NSDictionary *dict in list) {
        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        span.latitudeDelta = 0.3;
        span.longitudeDelta = 0.3;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

        location.latitude = [[dict valueForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
        location.longitude = [[dict valueForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];

        if (location.latitude == 0.0 && location.longitude == 0.0)
            return;

        region.span = span;
        region.center = location;

        MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        point.coordinate = location;
        point.title = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];

        [map addAnnotation:point];
        [map setRegion:region animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)constructList {
    int n = 0;
    for (NSDictionary *dict in list) {
        UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100*n, 320, 100)];
        container.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
        button.tag = n;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [container addSubview:button];


        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nAddress: %@\nPhone: %@\nWork Time: %@", [dict valueForKey:@"name"], [dict valueForKey:@"address"], [dict valueForKey:@"phone"], [dict valueForKey:@"workTime"]];
        UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 80)];
        nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        nameLabel.text = str;
        nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0];
        [container addSubview:nameLabel];


        UIView *separator = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 99, 320, 1)];
        separator.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        [container addSubview:separator];


        [contentSV addSubview:container];


        n++;
        contentSV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 100*n);
    }
}

- (float)distanceBetweenLat1:(float)tlat1 lon1:(float)tlon1 lat2:(float)tlat2 lon2:(float)tlon2 {
    float result = 0.0;
    int R = 6371;

    float currentLatitude = tlat1;
    float currentLongtitude = tlon1;

    float lat2 = tlat2;
    float lon2 = tlon2;

    float dLat = (lat2-currentLatitude)*M_PI/180;
    float dLon = (lon2-currentLongtitude)*M_PI/180;
    float nlLat = currentLatitude*M_PI/180;
    lat2 = lat2*M_PI/180;

    float a = sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2) +  sin(dLon/2) * sin(dLon/2) * cos(nlLat) * cos(lat2);
    float c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
    result = R * c;

    return result;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    selectedAnnTitle = [view.annotation title];

    return;

    DetailVC *sampleVC = [[DetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sampleVC animated:YES];


    NSString *ttl = [view.annotation title];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in list) {
        if ([[dict valueForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:ttl]) {
            [sampleVC updateViewWithDict:dict];
        }
    }

    [map deselectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:NO];
}

- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    DetailVC *sampleVC = [[DetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sampleVC animated:YES];


    int n = 0;
    for (NSDictionary *dict in list) {
        if (n == [sender tag]) {
            [sampleVC updateViewWithDict:dict];
        }
        n++;
    }
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    NSLog(@"didUpdateUserLocation");

    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView viewForAnnotation:userLocation];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;

    if (!userLocationUpdated) {
        if (userLocation.coordinate.latitude > 0.1 && userLocation.coordinate.longitude > 0.1) {
         //   NSLog(@"SORT BY DISTANCE");

            userLocationUpdated = YES;

            for (int i = 0; i < [list count]; i++) {
                NSMutableDictionary *record = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[list objectAtIndex:i]];

                float latitude = [[record valueForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
                float longitude = [[record valueForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];

                float dist = [self distanceBetweenLat1:map.userLocation.coordinate.latitude lon1:map.userLocation.coordinate.longitude lat2:latitude lon2:longitude];
                NSNumber *distN = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:dist];
                [record setObject:distN forKey:@"distance"];

              [list replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:record];
            }

            NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
            NSArray *itemsListSorted = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:list];
            itemsListSorted = [itemsListSorted sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];

            for (UIView *view in contentSV.subviews) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < [itemsListSorted count]; i++) {
                UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100*i, 320, 100)];
                container.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
                button.tag = i;
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [container addSubview:button];


                NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nAddress: %@\nPhone: %@\nWorkTime: %@", [[itemsListSorted objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"], [[itemsListSorted objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"address"], [[itemsListSorted objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"phone"], [[itemsListSorted objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"workTime"]];
                UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 80)];
                nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
                nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
                nameLabel.text = str;
                nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0];
                [container addSubview:nameLabel];


                UILabel *distanceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 2, 300, 21)];
                distanceLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
                distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f км", [[[itemsListSorted objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"distance"] floatValue]];
                distanceLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0];
                distanceLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
                [container addSubview:distanceLabel];


                UIView *separator = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 99, 320, 1)];
                separator.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
                [container addSubview:separator];


                [contentSV addSubview:container];


                contentSV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 100*(i+1));
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a lot more code than we need to see. Please reduce to the essential part that does not work.

Comment: Why are you using float and not double? Using float means you lose so much precision, you have to do a very careful analysis of your calculation for numerical stability. Have you done that? Do you know what it means? If you don't, use double.

Comment: You should really, really have a look at UITableViewController. At least if you ever have more than three items to display.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort by distance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769492/sort-by-distance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are *numerous* issues with this code (the least of which are some minor precision issues with the distance calculation), *the problem is not with the distance calculation*.

The detail view controller shows incorrect data because it is given the data from the `list` array which is ***not*** itself sorted by distance.

In the `didUpdateUserLocation` delegate method, the contents of `list` are copied to a *local* array named `itemsListSorted`.

Only the `itemsListSorted` array is sorted by distance and then the display is updated using this *local* array.

But the original `list` array (which the `buttonTapped` method uses as the source of the data to send to the detail view controller) is *never* updated.

So if "Central Office" is at index 0 in `list` but gets moved to index 2 in `itemsListSorted`, the display shows the correct position but when you tap on it, the `buttonTapped` method sends the item at index 2 from the `list` array which does *not* have "Central Office" (it's still at index 0 in `list`).

One way to fix this problem is to stop using a local array and sort the `list` array directly.

In `didUpdateUserLocation`, you could replace these two lines:

```
NSArray *itemsListSorted = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:list];
itemsListSorted = [itemsListSorted sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

with this:

```
[list sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

and then replace all references to `itemsListSorted` in the same method with `list`.

---

Regarding the other issues with the code, there is not enough room to point them all out or explain them in one answer.  However, here are just a few highlights:

- Instead of a manually creating a "table view", use an actual `UITableView`.
- Instead of manually calculating distance between coordinates, use the `distanceFromLocation` method in the `CLLocation` class *or* the `MKMetersBetweenMapPoints` function.
- In `viewForAnnotation`, you should return `nil` if `annotation` is of type `MKUserLocation` otherwise it will appear as a red pin just like the others.
- Use ARC instead of manual memory management.